# Setting compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion using productFlavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

our app is using product flavors in the build.gradle file to adjust configurations for different devices. I've been through the documentation on flavors in the [Android Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), and attempted to set the compileSdkVersion using android.setCompileSdkVersion(...). However, when I print out the compile version in applicationVariants.all, this doesn't seem to be applied to different flavors.

I've looked into adding a preprocessor task similar to what [Crashlytics is doing](http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/defining-custom-pre-and-post-processing-tasks-in-gradle/), but I would like to avoid this route if possible.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Building different APK's for different versions of Android seems like an odd strategy. I would suggest building a single APK with (a) logic to handle things differently in Java, and (b) different resources provided, depending on API version.

Comment: Trying to change compileSdkVersion doesn't make sense -- you don't want to build different flavors against different versions of the SDK. You ought to be able to set targetSdkVersion on a per-flavor basis though.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs. If I was going to change the targetSDK where does Android studio look for this value i.e. what directory should I place customAndroid.jar so that the compiler recognizes it. Is there a syntax here that Im not aware of like in the dependency section of build.gradle where I can specify a local file

Comment: If you are making a build for say FirePhone and regular Android devices it's not such a far fetched idea. The issue with the FirePhone is that is requires compileSdkVersion "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17" if you want to use the fancy widgets. So if you split up the source code a bit it should in theory be possible to compile for both platforms in the same build script.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64985